# Зачем нужен оператор ? при вызове метода?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

При просмотре одно из обучающих видео увидел следующую запись:

```
public event EventHandler Boom;

protected virtual void OnBoom();
{
  Boom?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

А конкретно интересен оператор '?' при вызове метода Invoke на событии. Зачем  нужен данный оператор? Какую роль он выполняет если применяется подобным образом при вызове методов? Касательно этого куска кода, который некачественно вырезан из контекста, информация не интересна. Нужно общее предназначение оператора '?'.

Comment: Синтактический сахар, чтобы не писать `if(Boom != null) Boom.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);`. И оператор идет вместе с точкой `?.`.

Comment: Вопрос не дубликат, а объяснение того же предмета с обратной стороны. ИМХО.

Comment: @Kromster Это и называется дубликат. Никто не говорит что этот вопрос плохой или не нужен, просто у этих вопросов общий пул ответов.

Comment: @vp_arth "Чем забивать гвозди? - молотком" и "Что забивать молотком? - гвозди". Вопросы хоть и с *"общим пулом ответов"*, но все же разные (хотя и связанные).

Comment: Поэтому(вопросы разные, ответы нет) и существует механизм связывания таких вопросов - "закрытие как дубликата". Это отличается от "закрытия вопросов плохого качества".

Answer (score 9):

Начиная с C# 6.0 в языке появился оператор условного `null` (Null-Conditional Operator) или, как его нередко называют, элвис-оператор. Он позволяет упростить проверку на значение `null` в условных конструкциях.

И в данном примере, если `Boom == null`, вызов `Invoke` не произойдет. Если `Boom != null`, то вызов произойдет.

Общее предназначение оператора таково - если переменная, которая стоит перед `?`, равна `null`, то вызов метода на этом объекте не произойдет.